# Retrieving Facebook album covers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get covers of albums, and have user to choose an album, and then choose a photo in the album. As the first step, currently my plan is using basic `HTTP` requests (with `AngularJS` `$resource`):

1. get `user.id`
2. query `graph.facebook.com/user.id/albums/`, to get a list of `album.id` and `album.cover_photo`
3. query for each `album` via `graph.facebook.com/album.cover_photo/` to get `cover_photo.images` and pick one image of the right size
4. After the user has picked an album, use the previous obtained `album.id` to query `graph.facebook.com/album.id/photos`, and now I have all photos' url of all size, most of which will not be used.

That sounds like quite a lot of queries, and in the 4th step I will obtained quite a lot of unnecessary infomation, I wonder if there are better ways (say I only need images of `height` `960px`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do steps 1 and 2 in a single step:

```
/me?fields=id,albums{id,cover_photo}
```

For your step three, there's no direct way to do this via Graph API call, meaning that you have to filter the sizes in your application

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/album/photos
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo

For your step 4, there's the same case as with step 3. You have to parse the result data. What you could do is to use the Batch API to wrap the steps 1/2 and 3.

If you can use FQL (meaning you have a <=v2.0 app), you can also use FQL to do steps 1,2,3 at once:

```
select owner, album_object_id, object_id, images from photo where pid in (select cover_pid from album where owner=me())
```

Comment: See my edit concerning FQL. If it helped please accept my answer.